# Fluxbox Lightdm nautilus

Tags: unity, nautilus, lightdm, fluxbox

I recently started using fluxbox, I'm using Lightdm as a desktop manager and was using gnome/unity before fluxbox.

I'm facing a few troubles while trying to adapt to this new window manager, the first one (and slightly odd) is this one:

Everytime I try to open Nautilus, the background changes to my unity ubuntu's background and when I right click on desktop's background (to reload fluxbox which was my first try to fix the problem) a unity folder options menu pops up (the one "New Folder", "Paste" etc. options ).

There's another thing that I'm not really sure about:
Is it ok that I use Lightdm just for the login screen? I simply change the window manager there to fluxbox and log in my computer normally with fluxbox.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be fine to use lightdm to select fluxbox. Next, to fix the nauitlus issue

install gnome-tweak-tool

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

then, use the command

```
gnome-tweak-tool
```

under desktop, look for "have file manager handle the desktop" and make sure this option is set to off

see here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2080212

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 16.04 there is no such option as "have file manager handle the desktop".

You can use the command `fbsetbg -b -solid black` to set the background to black (using `fbsetroot`). It will also enable/restore fluxbox's desktop context menu.